# Reading image filenames from spans

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to have an Image Slider which reads Image names from spans. What's wrong with my code? Even the alert command not executed. How to fix this?

```
<html><head>
<title></title>
<script src="Default.aspx_files/jquery-1.js" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl"></script>
<script src="Default.aspx_files/General.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(function () {
                var i = 0;
                var banner = $('.imagesContainer span').map(function () {
                    return $.trim($(this).text())
                }).get();

                function fun() {
                    //How to init array here from inner text of spans?
                    i++;
                    if (i == banner.length) {
                        i = 0;
                    }
                    $('#img1').attr('src', '/slide/' + banner[i]);
                    alert('/slide/' + banner[i]);
                }
                setInterval(fun, 1000);
            })
        </script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="Default.aspx" id="form1">
        <div class="imagesContainer">
        <span>
            73defe4b-9819-4e12-b351-3813686e0c83.gif
        </span>
        <span>
            4c2ed116-500d-42ad-8aa5-983bf214d5d3.png
        </span>
        </div>
</form>
</body></html>
```

Comment: It is showing alert, check it here, http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/Ed7BU/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not that you didn't know but it worked on a change of `type="text/x-jquery-tmpl"` to `text/javascript` in your jquery inclusion.